# Angular 7 + Java Spring - Websocket returning 404

Tags: angular, spring, websocket, stomp, sockjs

I am trying to use Spring 4 Websocket and Angular 7 through @stomp/stompjs and SockJS library, however it keeps returning 404 not found, and connection to websocket keeps closing as a result.

**My configuration code at Spring:**

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class SocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/batch-socket").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/socketio/");
    }   
}
```

**SocketHandlerService.java to send a message template**

```java
@Service
public class SocketHandlerService  extends AbsLogger<SocketHandlerService> implements ApplicationListener<BrokerAvailabilityEvent> {

   private final MessageSendingOperations<String> messagingTemplate;

   @Autowired
   public SocketHandlerService(MessageSendingOperations<String> messagingTemplate) {
       this.messagingTemplate = messagingTemplate;      
   }

   public SocketDetails sendRestMessage() {
         ...some code...
                        this.messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/socketio/batchupdate", data);
         ...some code...            
     } 
   }
```

**Angular socket.service.ts to handle websockets at client side**

```js
  init() {
    let connectionUrl = this.baseUrl + "batch-socket";

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let config = new StompConfig();
        config.heartbeatOutgoing = 5000;
        config.heartbeatIncoming = 5000;
        config.webSocketFactory = function () {
          return new SockJS(connectionUrl, null, { transports: ['websocket' , 'xhr-streaming','xhr-polling' ] });
        }
        config.debug = function (str) {
          console.log("@socketDebug: " + str)
        }
      this.client = new Client();
      this.client.configure(config);

      enableLogs && console.log(this.client);
      console.log("@socketSvc: starting connection...");

      const _this = this;
      this.client.onConnect = function (frame) {
        console.log("@socketSvc: connection established.");
        console.log(frame);
        _this.state = new BehaviorSubject<any>(SocketClientState.ATTEMPTING);
        _this.state.next(SocketClientState.CONNECTED);
        resolve(frame.headers['user-name']);
      }

      this.client.onWebSocketClose = function (msg){
        console.log("@socketSvc: connection closed.");
        console.log(msg);
      }

      this.client.activate();
    });

  }
```

I have checked that the endpoint urls match and that the domain for both server and client that is using is the same as well. However when deployed the following console output appears:

```
POST https://exampleWebsite.com/Portal/batch-socket/718/ky4ln33y/xhr_send?t=1576031555275 404 (Not Found)
                                                           main.7459b10fe35bab2c58d4.js:179295 

@socketDebug: Connection closed to https://exampleWebsite.com/Portal/batch-socket 
                                                           main.7459b10fe35bab2c58d4.js:179310 

@socketSvc: connection closed.                             main.7459b10fe35bab2c58d4.js:179311 

i {type: "close", bubbles: false, cancelable: false, timeStamp: 1576031555344, wasClean: false, …}bubbles: falsecancelable: falsecode: 1006reason: "Sending error: Error: http status 404"timeStamp: 1576031555344type: "close" wasClean: false__proto__: r
                                                           main.7459b10fe35bab2c58d4.js:179295 

@socketDebug: STOMP: scheduling reconnection in 5000ms
```

I have also took a look in the developer tools for web browser to check the network:
[network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiPuz.png)

May I know what is the issue for causing a close connection? Sometimes it takes a few tries before the websocket is successfully established. Other times it takes forever to have a successful connection.

Comment: give us more logs from server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code runs for me!!

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
         registry.addEndpoint("/batch-socket");
         registry.addEndpoint("/batch-socket").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

**Message-Handling Controller:**

```
@MessageMapping("/batch-socket")
@SendTo("/topic/messages")
public OutputMessage send(Message message) throws Exception {
    String time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(new Date());
    return new OutputMessage(message.getFrom(), message.getText(), time);
}
```

**Payload:**

```
public class Message {

    private String from;
    private String text;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try soon! May I know why there is duplicated endpoints and one with `withSockJS()` ? And does adding a prefix to the broker affects the overall websocket connection?

Comment: Ah!!! you can simply ignore the `registry.addEndpoint("/batch-socket");` if you are only using sockjs. but it's always good to have a fallback endpoint which can be used to create WebSocket connections

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! I would only get to deploy my code tomorrow, hopefully it gets fixed! :)